# docker-compose failed "ERROR: The Compose file"

Tags: docker-compose

```
   version: '3'
    services:
      mongo:
        image: mongo:4.2.8
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - 27017:27017
        volumes:
          - mongodb:/data/db
          - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
      pisignage-server:
        image: pisignage/pisignage-server:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
        volumes:
          - media:/media
          - data:/data
        depends_on:
          mongo:
            condition: service_started
    
    volumes:
      mongodb:
      mongodb_config:
      media:
      data:
```

So every singe time i try to compose I get following error:
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.pisignage-server.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array

Any Idea what I am missing?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, we have added a new docker-compose.yml file which takes care of these issues

Answer (score 1):

#1 depends_on should be an array e.g.

[image]

Also #2

> Version 3 no longer supports the condition form of depends_on.

see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on